# rails assert_redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

routes.rb

```
  map.resources :places do |places|
      places.resources :reviews  
  end
```

place model

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end
```

review model

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
end
```

In my reviews controller test I have the following assert_redirect_to statement

```
assert_redirected_to place_review_path(assigns(:place), assigns(:review))
```

but functional test fail with the following error

```
  1) Failure:
test_should_create_review(ReviewsControllerTest) [/test/functional/reviews_controller_test.rb:24]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/places/980190962/reviews/980190963> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/places/980190962>.

  2) Failure:
test_should_destroy_review(ReviewsControllerTest) [/test/functional/reviews_controller_test.rb:47]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/places/980190962/reviews.%23%3Creview:0xb74783a0%3E> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/places/980190962/reviews>.

  3) Failure:
test_should_update_review(ReviewsControllerTest) [/test/functional/reviews_controller_test.rb:39]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/places/980190962/reviews/980190962> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/places/980190962>.
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: I need the app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb file to be able to figure this out - at least the action in question.  Can you provide?

Answer (score 1):

The assert_redirect_to is working as expected. Instead, it looks like your ReviewsController is redirecting to unexpected places. assert_redirected_to appears to be functioning as it should. And all your failures stem from the fact that the url the action was redirected to does not match the url given to assert_redirected_to.

More specifically:

1. ReviewsController is redirecting to `place_path(assigns(:place))`.  Which is **inconsistent** with the standard Rails workflow. The assert expects `place_review_path(assigns(:place), assigns(:review))`
2. ReviewsController is redirecting to `place_reviews_path(assigns(:place))` which is consistent with the standard Rails workflow. The assert expects `place_review_path(assigns(:place), assigns(:review))`. However because destroy action removes the id of assigns(:review), so `place_review_path(assigns(:place), assigns(:review))` will fail to generate a proper url which explains the odd characters in the error message.
3. ReviewsController is redirecting to `place_path(assings(:place))`. Again this is **inconsistent** with the standard Rails workflow. The assert expects `place_review_path(assigns(:place), assigns(:review))`

The short version is, unless you've strayed from Rails conventions, the first and third failures listed your controller are redirecting to an unexpected place. The second failed assertion is just wrong.

Comment: So I was using redirect_to(@place, @review) in the controller.
The correct form seems to be redirect_to([@place, @review]).
It works now. Thanks!